# Chef : How to change owner of a directory in a dependent cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I have a base cookbook which creates few folders and set their owner as 'root'. My cookbook depends on the base cookbook but I want the owner of the directories (created in base cookbook )to be 'user'. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit those resources in your wrapper cookbook as follows:

```rb
edit_resource!(:directory, 'foo') do
  owner 'user'
end
```

assuming that the (previously included) base cookbook has the following definition:

```rb
directory "foo" do
  owner 'root'
end
```

See also [@coderanger's blog post](https://coderanger.net/rewind/).

---

A syntax variant, which is already available in older Chef versions would be:

```rb
resources('directory[foo]').owner 'user'
```